# Transform <g> attribute on map of d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have prepared one example of map in d3.js. I wanted to implement zoom on map with and node(contains circle, smiley and text. as of now i putted circle and smiley) on map shows the city of different countries. When i zoom over map i could not able to transform the  tag so smiley got misplace as per my logic. so how to transform only g tags on map. I don't want to transform shape(circle, images) inside  tag.

[My Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dmn0d11f/8/)

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .on("zoom",function() {
     g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
        d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
     g.selectAll(".node")
      .attr("width", function(){
        var self = d3.select(this);
        var r = 28 / d3.event.scale;  // set radius according to scale
        self.style("stroke-width", r < 4 ? (r < 2 ? 0.5 : 1) : 2);  // scale stroke-width
        return r;
    });
      g.selectAll(".circle")
      .attr("r", function(){
        var self = d3.select(this);
        var r = 8 / d3.event.scale;  // set radius according to scale
        self.style("stroke-width", r < 4 ? (r < 2 ? 0.5 : 1) : 2);  // scale stroke-width
        return r;
    });
});
```

Please anybody help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do semantic zooming, one would need to adjust the `width` and `height` of the smiley faces as well as adjust the `x` and `y` locations since the adjustments will change relative to the width/height:

```
 g.selectAll(".node")
 .attr("x", function(d) { return (projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]) - (8 / d3.event.scale); })
 .attr('y', function(d) { return (projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]) - (8 / d3.event.scale); })
 .attr('width', function () { return 20 / d3.event.scale; })
 .attr('height', function () { return 20 / d3.event.scale; })
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ktee4dLp/

Comment: Musi, Thanks for correction but i don't want to zoom smiley, only map should zoom. Just like semantic zoom for example (http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9167301) where image of plan get separated as we keep zooming.